# Add "field" to existing Databin

Tags: datadrop

I have a Databin I created:

```
CreateDatabin["Name" -> "MEAUREMENTS","Interpretation"-> 
                                    {"measure1"->"Integer",
                "measure2"->"Integer",
                "measure3"->"Integer"}]
```

Currently, data has been added.  I would like to add an additional "field", I guess that is called an interpretation.  I am confused on terminology.  Can I add an additional "field" to existing databin or will I need to make new databin and copy the existing data to the new databin?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a new field by just uploading new data (to the existing Databin) with the new field specified.

For example, if your previous addition was:

```
https://datadrop.wolframcloud.com/api/v1.0/Add?bin=id&measure1=45&measure2=55&measure3=65
```

Your new one would simply include the new field with its new data:

```
https://datadrop.wolframcloud.com/api/v1.0/Add?bin=id&measure1=45&measure2=55&measure3=65&measure4=75
```

Comment: Could you add a Mathematica code? From what I see you are not adding a field to data but overwriting with with bigger set.

Comment: Doesn't Add just append more data to the Databin, and if it has further fields specified then they are added for all existing elements and simply set to empty?

Comment: In the second call you need to know `measure1=45&measure2=55` etc. I wouldn't call it adding if you need to provide all of them. And if those first three are not needed, why have you put it there?

Comment: I just made the 2nd call the same but it doesn't have to be I guess. Just adding a single call with a new field will create the new field but leave the existing fields as empty.
As deleting is tedious when you have data to cleanse in a Databin I wanted to given an example that shows similar data being added but also with a new field.